# Is there defined behaviour if USB HID report transmission cleanly concludes ‘early’?

Tags: usb, hid

I'm implementing a low speed USB HID device that has reports that are longer than 8 bytes (64 bytes). I therefore have to transfer the reports in multiple 8 byte USB transactions (8 transactions for 64 bytes).

Mostly, though, the reports contain long streams of zeros at the end because the later fields are barely ever used. I could get higher throughput if I didn’t have to transmit the ‘useless’ end parts.

I'm not in control of the protocol, so I can't redefine the reports in the HID descriptor to be shorter.

Can I stop transferring when I reach the zeros, and rely on the host to pad the received report to the full length? There are some *suggestions* in the HID spec that this should work:

> • A report might span one or more USB transactions. For example, an
> application that has 10-byte reports will span at least two USB
> transactions in a low-speed device.
>
> • If there are multiple reports in
> a top level collection then all reports, except the longest which
> exceed wMaxPacketSize for the endpoint must terminate with a short
> packet. The longest report does not require a short packet terminator.

And, indeed, it seems work to in real life: if I terminate report transmission ‘early’ with a short packet, the host behaves as if it received the report successfully.

But I don't see anywhere in the spec that explicitly discusses what a host should do if reception if a report is concluded early, so I’m unsure if this behaviour can be relied upon. Can it?